# Получить числовую матрицу из столбца DataFrame, состоящего из CSV строк

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, dataframe

Значит содержимое dataframe
[image: Значит содержимое dataframe]

Хочу получить Sequence. Получаю вообще такое. Откуда берется Id. Я не очень хорошо понимаю. Задача - получить Sequence в виде строки, разбить на массив и перевести в цифры. Тип dftrain.Sequence - object
[image]

Comment: можете привести пример нескольких строк вашего CSV в виде __текста__ или выложить CSV на какой-нибудь файлообменник? Данные в виде картинок использовать не получится!

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Да. Вот https://dropmefiles.com/xG3EL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сначала разобъем CSV строки в матрицу:

```
In [191]: df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\download\IntegerSeqTrain.csv', index_col='Id')

In [192]: r = df.Sequence.str.split(',', expand=True)

In [193]: r
Out[193]:
        0     1      2        3          4            5                     6    ...    341   342   343   344   345   346   347
Id                                                                               ...
3         1     3     13       87       1053        28576               2141733  ...   None  None  None  None  None  None  None
7         1     2      1        5          5            1                    11  ...   None  None  None  None  None  None  None
8         1     2      4        5          8           10                    16  ...   None  None  None  None  None  None  None
11        1     8     25       83        274         2275                132224  ...   None  None  None  None  None  None  None
13        1   111  12211  1343211  147753211  16252853211         1787813853211  ...   None  None  None  None  None  None  None
15        1     1      1        1          1            1                     1  ...   None  None  None  None  None  None  None
16      840  1320   1680     2520       3192         3432                  4920  ...   None  None  None  None  None  None  None
...     ...   ...    ...      ...        ...          ...                   ...  ...    ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
227681    7     7      3        2          3            9                     5  ...   None  None  None  None  None  None  None
227682    1     0      1        0          0            0                     0  ...   None  None  None  None  None  None  None
227683    0     0      4     1198    1829388  23796035743      2142967506078650  ...   None  None  None  None  None  None  None
227684    0    -1     -1       -1         -1     10324303  -6586524273069171148  ...   None  None  None  None  None  None  None
227686    0     1      9       85        801         7549                 71145  ...   None  None  None  None  None  None  None
227689    2     3      3        4          6            4                     5  ...   None  None  None  None  None  None  None
227690    5     7    179      229        439          557                  6113  ...   None  None  None  None  None  None  None

[113845 rows x 348 columns]
```

у вас встречаются целые числа, состоящие из 285 цифр, поэтому преобразовать такие строки в числа не получится:

```
In [184]: r.applymap(lambda x: len(x) if x else 0).max()
Out[184]:
0      128
1      144
2      271
3      254
4      285
5      189
6      215
      ...
341      1
342      1
343      1
344      2
345      2
346      1
347      1
Length: 348, dtype: int64

In [185]: r.applymap(lambda x: len(x) if x else 0).max().max()
Out[185]: 285
```

максимальное беззнаковое целое для Numpy/Pandas:

```
In [194]: np.iinfo(np.uint64)
Out[194]: iinfo(min=0, max=18446744073709551615, dtype=uint64)
```

Comment: А каким образом тогда можно обучить временной ряд. Например самый простой метод: наивный алгоритм. В качестве тек. момента времени выступают индексы массива, но сами числа должны быть в массиве как я понимаю

Comment: @StenFord, попробуйте задать отдельный SO вопрос с небольшим, но воспроизводимым примером даных и примером того, что вы хотите получить на выходе...

Comment: Есть данные, с которыми вы уже ознакомились. Сама задача - обучить систему угадывать следующее число в последовательности. Я пользуюсь https://habr.com/company/ods/blog/327242/. Необходимо реализовать алгоритмы, скользящее усреднение, линейная регрессия и.т.д. Мне нужно данные привести в такой вид, чтобы я мог скормить функциями. Как я понимаю - преобразовать в массив, индексы массива - в качестве промежутка времени

Comment: @StenFord, советую изучить ["Как задать хороший вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), ["Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и задавать вопросы соответственно. ;)

Comment: Ладно, в следующий раз учту) Спасибо за помощь, одну проблему решили  + 200 сверху:D